# Writing `.^` in math mode (element-wise power in Julia)

Tags: math-mode, code

I would like to write `.^` in latex, in a math expression. I tried using \texttt{.^} but I get

> ^ only allowed in math mode.

So I tried escaping it \texttt{.^} but this didn't work either. Essentially I would like to write something like `a.^` but in latex.

Comment: Try `\verb|.^|`

Comment: It works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `.^` seems to be input syntax for the Julia programming language, this may not be the ideal notation in mathematical typesetting. (Mainly because it consists of two symbols *next to* each other.) If there is no common symbol to represent this operation in mathematical equations, I would recommend inventing an appropriate one. For example

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\elempow{\mathbin{\hat\cdot}}

\begin{document}

\(a \elempow b\)

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I would assume that OP is looking to type "In Julia, one would type `a.^b`".  Your example wouldn't make sense to me if I saw it in that context.

Comment: @Teepeemm in that case it wouldn't, you're right. However, using math mode at all wouldn't make sense then. This would call for a listing package or at the very least `\verb`. Since OP specified that this should go into math mode, I assume their application is about the mathematics, not the syntax.